# LibMemcached crash php-fpm

Tags: php, memcached, libmemcached

I have PHP:

> root@15048:/# php -v
>
> PHP 7.0.3-1~dotdeb+8.1 (cli) ( NTS ) Copyright
>   (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c)
>   1998-2016 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies

With installed memcached library:

[image]

And I have wrote class for working with memcached:

```
public $cache;

public function __construct() {
    $this->cache = new Memcached();
    $this->cache->setOption(Memcached::OPT_LIBKETAMA_COMPATIBLE, true);
    if (!count($this->cache->getServerList())) {
        $this->cache->addServer('127.0.0.1', 11211);
    }
}

public function get( $key ) {
    return $this->cache->get( $key );
}

public function set( $key, $var, $time ) {
    /*if ( $this->cache->set( $key, $var, $time ) )
        return true;*/
    return false;
}

public function flush() {
    if ( $this->cache->flush() )
        return true;
    return false;
}

public function __destruct() {
    $this->cache->quit();
}
```

But when I uncomment "set" function, JUST uncomment, and NEVER call it, php crash...

I have tried memcached "add" function has same issue...

> [26-Mar-2016 14:26:42] WARNING: [pool www] child 15541 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 26.168556 seconds from start
>
> [26-Mar-2016 14:26:42] NOTICE: [pool www] child 15566 started
>
> [26-Mar-2016 14:26:42] WARNING: [pool www] child 15542 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 10.321759 seconds from start
>
> [26-Mar-2016 14:26:42] NOTICE: [pool www] child 15567 started
>
> [26-Mar-2016 14:26:43] WARNING: [pool www] child 15567 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 1.305421 seconds from start
>
> [26-Mar-2016 14:26:43] NOTICE: [pool www] child 15578 started
>
> [26-Mar-2016 14:26:44] WARNING: [pool www] child 15540 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 28.413800 seconds from start
>
> [26-Mar-2016 14:26:44] NOTICE: [pool www] child 15579 started

Comment: Memcached uses igbinary and igbinary is broken in the build of dotdeb.org. https://www.dotdeb.org/2016/03/04/php-7-0-4-for-jessie/#comment-35021

Comment: @charlotte-dunois thank you, disable this module helps